# Viewing single product details

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs, e-commerce

I am building an e-commerce project, and at the point where I want the user to be able to view the details of a product once they click on a "view" button. I have already rendered the products from a MySQL database to the front end and each of these products has a unique id. How do I go about this? I will include the code below:

This is my index.ejs file:

```
        <% result.forEach(function(product){ %>

        <div class="product_card col-lg-3">
            <img src="images\<%= product.main_img %>">
            <div class="product_content">
                <p><%= product.product_name %></p>
                <h5>£<%= product.price %></h5>
                <a href="<%= product.id %>" role="button">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <% }) %>
```

Below is my app.js file pointing to the single product page where I want tyhe details of each product to be displayed once view button is clicked from the index.ejs page:

```
app.get('/singleproduct', function(req, res){

res.render('singleproduct')  
})
```

And below is the singleproduct.ejs page where I want the products details to be displayed:

```
<% result.forEach(function(product){ %>
<div class="single_product_main">
<div class="single_product_imgs">
    
  
   <img src="images\<%= product.image %>" alt=""> 
    <div class="small_imgs">
        <img src="images\<%= product.small_img1 %>" alt="">  
        <img src="images\<%= product.small_img2 %>" alt="">  
        <img src="images\<%= product.small_img3 %>" alt=""> 
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="single_product_content"> 
 <h2><%= product.product_name %></h2> 
 <h5>£<%= product.price %></h5> 
 <p><%= product.product_description %></p> 
</div>



  <% }) %>
```

Comment: How is it a single product page if you loop on products? Also, you need a parameter `'/singleproduct'/:id`

Comment: so I am looping on products to display all the products. but the single product page is supposed to give more information on any product if I should click on it. I don't want to create a separate page for each product to view its details. Hope its clearer?

Comment: Why is there `result.forEach(function(product)` in the single product view?

Comment: I am guessing it is not supposed to be there since I want to render only the details of one product and not all the products

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code

```
<a href="/singleproduct/<%= product.id %>" role="button">View</a>
```

```js
app.get('/singleproduct/:id', function(req, res){
  const id = req.params.id
  const data = getTheProductDataFromSomewhere(id)
  res.render('singleproduct', { product: data })
})
```

```
<div class="single_product_main">
<div class="single_product_imgs">
    
  
   <img src="images\<%= product.image %>" alt=""> 
    <div class="small_imgs">
        <img src="images\<%= product.small_img1 %>" alt="">  
        <img src="images\<%= product.small_img2 %>" alt="">  
        <img src="images\<%= product.small_img3 %>" alt=""> 
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="single_product_content"> 
 <h2><%= product.product_name %></h2> 
 <h5>£<%= product.price %></h5> 
 <p><%= product.product_description %></p> 
</div>
```

Comment: could you please throw some light on the rationale behind the ```const data = getTheProductDataFromSomewhere(id)``` ? Where am I getting this data from because I am using a mysql database

Comment: From mysql database

Comment: okay thanks. Will work with that and revert.